# launch screen ghost?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4

1. create a new window based app in xcode4 named 'TestLaunchScreen'
2. right click on launch image in the project settings and select 'select file' and choose a launch image
3. runs fine and shows launch screen
4. delete project folder
5. create the same project with the same name in the same location
6. in project settings launch image it says 'no image specified' but when i launch it shows the launch screen from the last app i made?

where outside the project folder is this setting being saved and transfered to new apps with the same name in the same location? if i was on windows i would guess the registry...

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just try to CLEAN your project, and try Uninstalling your app from the simulator with the X that appears when you keep pressing on the icon in the springboard.

Comment: i tried clean did not work... and i thought i tried 'reset content and settings' from simulator... but i just tried it now and it seemed to work... thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have a file in the folder named `Default.png`, then even if you do not set the default image in the `Info.plist` file, this will appear as the launch image.

If that isn't the problem, then try deleting the app from the simulator, select Build/Clean All Targets, and launch the app again.

Comment: i do not have that image there i said i deleted the project folder and recreated it

Comment: @rakkarage: Then the image may still be on the simulator version. See my edit above.